# Error while trying to call np.ravel_multi_index function in python to convert subscripts to linear Indices for Three-Dimensional Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to use the np.ravel_multi_index function in order to convert y,x matrix subscripts to a linear index.
Both y and x are ndarrays of shape/dimension (240,1236,4). Basically the line of code which I used is as follow:

```
lin_indices = np.ravel_multi_index((y, x), dims=x.shape)
```

I add an image which shows how y and x arrays are built:
[image]

When I call the abovementioned function, I am getting the following error:

{ValueError}ValueError('parameter multi_index must be a sequence of length 3')

In order to create y and x parameters of your own you can use the following lines:

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(240, 1236, 4))
y = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(240, 1236, 4))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: thanks to the comments below I see that in order to get a three dimension array I need to provide 3 arguments, one to every dimension. But I would like help to build it if possible.

Comment: reread the multiindex docs.  You specify a 3d shape.  The 1st arguments is then supposed to be a 
3 tuple of arrays.

Comment: Hmm it took me a while but I see what you mean. Do you have any solution in mind?

Comment: Can you explain the output you want?

Comment: @MechanicPig Every int in the x and y arrays represent subscripts to a 240,1236 image. I want to get the linear indices to that image if I sorted it in one column/row. I'd like the output to have the same dimensions as x and y arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the first two dimensions to argument `dims`, which will interpret each pair of values in `x` and `y` as subscripts for a 240 * 1236 array and ravel them into 1d subscripts:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(240, 1236, 4))
>>> y = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(240, 1236, 4))
>>> np.ravel_multi_index((y, x), dims=x.shape[:2]).shape
(240, 1236, 4)
```